# Extension builder Content Element type "content element" has no rendering definition

Tags: typo3, frontend, backend, fluid, extbase

I did the example brought by Tobias Liegl: "FCE (Flexible Content Elements) ohne TemplaVoila" in http://www.slideshare.net/TobiasLiegl/fce-ohne-templavoila.

But i get an error that says: 
ERROR: Content Element type "contentelements_contactbox" has no rendering definition!
I'm working on TYPO3 6.1
Any ideas?

Comment: Where do you get this error message? In the backend when trying to add the content element or in the frontend when trying to see an already added element?

Comment: That's a FE message. In oldstyle TS, it would appear when in a content object there was no (working) renderObj. In Fluid, there's probably something wrong with a view(helper), or maybe some TS (settings?) not included

Answer (score -2):

I got the same message after i copied an extension built with the Extension Builder from a local development system to my live environment. I activated the plugin in Extension Manager and everthing worked, i could add the new content element from the Add Content Wizard.

Then i found this page:
[Reason #6 for Choosing TYPO3](http://castironcoding.com/resources/our-blog/sp/view/show/post/reason-6-for-choosing-typo3-custom-content-elements-and-extbase-again-part-23.html?tx_cicblog_list%5Bcontroller%5D=Posts&cHash=13d15edce9ae768be7dd36a140811b82)

One of the comments pointed out to clear all caches - that did the trick for me.

Hope that helps!

Sebastian